# Auto Sort Function in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm looking to get items in my to-do lists on this spreadsheet automatically sorted based on priority # (1 at the top, and so on) but I want it to automatically sort each time it is edited. Is this possible with the sort function? Thanks for your help in advance!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KHqe8Kvz0e-pbEnoVN6f6vyIyA7VNtuTSQn40q1qGD8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

it's not. you will need a script which will do exactly what you request. for example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");             // SHEET NAME
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");                  // RANGE TO SORT

function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]);        // COLUMN NUMBER TO SORT
}                                                    // TRUE/FALSE FOR ASCENDING/DESCENDING
```

### _________________________________________________________

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for this info. Where could I add this in Google Sheets?

Comment: @RyanGiggey under script editor. you need to paste it there, save it and authorize it

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work...must be doing something stupid here. Would you mind taking a look? This is editable now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KHqe8Kvz0e-pbEnoVN6f6vyIyA7VNtuTSQn40q1qGD8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RyanGiggey try like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr9aD.png and if you authorized it - it will work (tested)