# Google Sheets Script: Move row based on dropdown AND auto-sort by date

Tags: function, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm creating a team task tracker in Google Sheets ([like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kOOZCxZcjVVUv-jUR03qCCUGgXQbmmWJ4D8qOSd1yUs/edit?usp=sharing)) containing Task Name, Task Status via dropdown (New, In Progress, Completed, etc), Due Date and Task Notes. There is a tab with all New tasks, a tab for In Progress tasks, Completed tasks, etc. I want the **row of task data to move** off of the New tab to the appropriate tab when the drop down status has been selected to anything other than "New" and I want each tab of task data to be **sorted by due date**. I've been able to achieve each of these two things on their own but I cannot get them to work together.

1. Move row of data to the appropriate tab in the sheet, based on the Status (dropdown item: New, In Progress, Completed, etc.) selected. For this, I used the following script which works to move the row to the bottom line of the destination sheet when status is changed:

   ```
   function onEdit(e) {
     const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
     const r = e.range;
     if (r.columnStart != 2 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value == src.getName()) return;
     const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(e.value);
     src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,5).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5));
     }
   ```
2. List the tasks (in each tab) by due date from the items due soonest at the top to items due latest at the bottom. For this, I used [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57442320/auto-sort-function-in-google-sheets) also shown below and the script worked for me, but I couldn't figure out how to combine this script or something similar, with the existing script I have to auto-move rows based on the dropdown item selected.

```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");             // SHEET NAME
   var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");                  // RANGE TO SORT
   function onEdit(e)  {
   range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]);        // COLUMN NUMBER TO SORT
   }
```

I'd really appreciate any help auto-moving rows based on the dropdown item AND auto-sorting the data by due date! Thank you so much.

Comment: If you post enough information in the question so that I don't have to look at your spreadsheet then I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the sort() method after moving the row.

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 2 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value == src.getName()) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(e.value);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,5).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  dest.getDataRange().offset(1, 0).sort({column: 4, ascending: true});
}
```

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Reference:

- [sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)